# How to space '|'?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I write a lot `|`, for instance, `even numbers = \{ z | z \in Z, z mod 2 = 0 \}`. But the space around `|` does not look enough... I tried `\mathbin{|}` and `\quad |  \quad`, they do not look great either...

Could anyone tell me a conventional way to put space around `|`?

Comment: How about `\mid`?

Comment: You should write `z \equiv 0 \pmod{2}` or `z \bmod 2 = 0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you were on the right track, but it's `\mathrel{|}`, for which LaTeX has the abbreviation `\mid`.

The formula should be more correctly written as

```
\{\, z \mid z\in Z, z \bmod 2 = 0 \,\}
\{\, z \mid z\in Z, z \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \,\}
\{\, z\in Z \mid z \bmod 2 = 0 \,\}
\{\, z\in Z \mid z \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \,\}
```

Take your pick. If you write something like "even numbers = {z ...}" (which I don't like, preferring to say "the even numbers are those in the set {z ...}"), put the equals sign inside the formula

```
even numbers~\(=\{\, ... \,\}
```

or, if the text is already inside math mode (in an alignment, for instance), use

```
\text{even numbers} = \{\, ... \,\}
```

Note that `\text` is provided by the **amsmath** package.

Comment: I wonder if there is a semantically better way to typeset set definitions, as `\,` does not appeal to me.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov The `\,` is a matter of personal taste. One way to avoid it might be to define `\lset` and `\rset` to be respectively `\{\,` and `\,\}`. Or directly redefining `\{` *provided it's not used elsewhere*: `\renewcommand\{{\lbrace\,}` and similarly for `\}` with `\rbrace`.

Comment: The `braket` package provides the commands `\set` (online math mode) and `\Set` (display math mode) to fill just this need.

Comment: @Mico It's disputable if this is really an improvement. :)

Comment: @egreg: I'm with you -- I just insert the spacing commands to the right of the opening curly and to the left of the closing curly brace by hand; remembering the syntax of `\set{...` is too cumbersome, given the relatively low frequency of needing to use it arises in my work.